# How to move specific Kindle books to a new collection in the Kindle app for PC using a keyboard?

Tags: kindle

I've got samples and complete books sitting in my "all items" section but I want to move certain books to a new collection.  Is there any way to select multiple books by a keyboard and move them to a new section, specifically under "collection"?

Win 7.
IE 9.

Comment: Does shift work?

Comment: Shift by itself?

Comment: Shift, then use the arrow keys...

Comment: No, I need to copy/ move books to a new collection folder in the app.  I'm lost.